# Xcode 4, How to make other buttons fall off the screen after one is pushed.

Tags: xcode, ibaction, gravity

As an example, I have 5 IBActions declared. When I push one, I want the other 4 to fall down off the screen. Any idea how to do this? Would I define a translation for each other IBAction??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is quite a broad question. Have you tried anything yourself or do you have a specific point that is blocking you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UIButton is a UIView. You can animate movement of a UIView; that movement can be to a position offscreen. (See the section under "animation" in the UIView class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) You *might* then want to remove the now-invisible buttons from their superview (in which case you'd need to retain them somehow or they might cease to exist), but you don't have to.

You will need a way to refer to the UIButtons. You can use IBOutlets for this, or you can "tag" the buttons in Interface Builder and use `-[UIView viewWithTag:]` to find the buttons you want to animate.

For a whole lot more on animation, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html